# What if we change size in fwrite( ,size, , ),will there be any change in o/p?

Tags: c, fwrite

```
fwrite(file_buffer,1,sizeof(file_buffer),fp);
```

In this it is stated that the value `1` is `This is the size in bytes of each element to be written`.
My question is, what if we write `2` or `3` or any other no. in place of `1`?
Will there be any change in o/p?

Thank you.

Comment: What did you expect ? that this argument is useless ?

Comment: Of course there will. While this is really a RTFM question, the declaration for `fwrite` is `size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);`. It will write `nmemb * size` bytes. If you change `size` -- what will happen?